# Credit Card Payments in iOS (3-D Secure?)

Tags: ios, credit-card, payment-processing, 3d-secure

So I'm wondering if implementing credit card payment sin iOS is possible?

This is the basic idea..

1. User finds a something on eCommerce app they want to buy
2. The app then gets their CC details and send it to a 3-D Secure merchant
3. User verifies their CC using the 3-D secure method
4. Payment gets accepted.

If this possible without breaking out into Safari?

What I have found out from some research

1. We could use something like: https://stripe.com/

However this provides two problems:

1a - I don't think the 2-D secure works here. 
1b - if the current eCommerce website is using a different method - we cannot integrate stripe into the app as this would mean changing the whole CC payment process?

So it seems the only way to do this would be this:

1. Load the CC payment info in a UIWebview (of the actual eCommerce website) and using the web view to load the site and the current 3-D Secure payment method?

It seems to me that CC payments overall are very limited in scope and scalability when not using services like PayPal and iAP?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3d secure (both SecureCode and Verified By Visa) must be done in a web browser, and more specifically in an iFrame.

The content of the iFrame is dynamically loaded by the card scheme to present a page hosted by the card **issuer** (to allow it to display the secret phrase). Checking of the password is also performed by card issuer, without any intervention by you.

There is no way to perform the 3d secure check outside of a web browser.

Comment: Right, I didn't realise that they had to be loaded in an iFrame. Going back to the original idea - isn't UIWebView a "mini" browser with an app anyway and could load this iFrame for 3D Secure? If this seems like a silly question - please forgive me, I am new to iOS development.

Comment: Just to add on what I stated - I can get the app to accept a CC payment - however, when the user taps confirm payment - I want something like a WebView to open up - display the 3D secure section with the users card details captured from the app - then once confirmed, close the web view and go back to the order confirmed page?

Comment: That seems feasible. You'd need to research integrating your app with an MPI (Merchant Plug-in Interface). It's the MPI which passes info to/from the Visa/MasterCard directory servers prior to presenting the iFrame. Developing your own MPI is possible, but it would need certifying with Visa/MasterCard (expensive).

Comment: Thanks Paul - you have been a great help. I will look into this MPI and see how it can be added into the app. When you say expensive - how expensive are we talking here? lastly - could I leave this MPI out of the equation all together?

Comment: If you want to do 3D secure, you need an MPI. Buying a 3rd party (pre-certified) implementation is cheaper than developing your own. However, even integrating with an existing MPI needs to be certified (free with Visa, not so with MasterCard). Drop me a mail if you want a bunch of official docs as a head start to your research

Comment: Hello, Did you guys find any solution for this? I want to achieve the same in my iOS application?

Comment: Yes I got it working perfectly fine. i did did as I stated above, used a UIWebView

Comment: @Tander did you add something special to normal webview workflow?

Comment: Nothing special @gaussblurinc - just hooked into UIWebViews callback methods to handle the response from the iFrame.